# Remove Comma from STUFF if I ony have one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to remove the comma at the end if there's only one value inside the stuff but, it should exists there's more than one value
thanks!

```
select
Names= (STUFF((
  SELECT ', ' +     CONCAT(
                CASE WHEN RegistryUser.FirstName IS NOT NULL AND RegistryUser.LastName IS NOT NULL THEN RegistryUser.FirstName ELSE App.FirstName END,
                ' ',
                CASE WHEN RegistryUser.FirstName IS NOT NULL AND RegistryUser.LastName IS NOT NULL THEN RegistryUser.LastName ELSE App.LastName END
            ) AS Names
    FROM ConsultingEventConsultant
            LEFT JOIN App
                ON ConsultingEventConsultant.AppID = App.AppID
            LEFT JOIN RegistryUser
                ON App.UserID = RegistryUser.UserID
            WHERE ConsultingEventConsultant.consultingeventid = 56428 
            and ConsultingEventConsultant.CECID != (SELECT TOP 1 CECID FROM ConsultingEventConsultant CEC WHERE CEC.ConsultingEventID = 56428 ORDER BY CECID)
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
             ), 1, 1, ''))
```

John Doe

John Doe, Sara Smith

Comment: Your STUFF() is removing the leading comma.  I suspect you have an empty name in your data.

Answer (score 1):

As John Cappelleti states you are removing the leading comma (not the the leading space though) and if there is a trailing comma then you have a blank row being returned.

To also remove the leading space just change the second 1 near the end to a 2 as below.

```
select
Names= (STUFF((
  SELECT ', ' +     CONCAT(
                CASE WHEN RegistryUser.FirstName IS NOT NULL AND RegistryUser.LastName IS NOT NULL THEN RegistryUser.FirstName ELSE App.FirstName END,
                ' ',
                CASE WHEN RegistryUser.FirstName IS NOT NULL AND RegistryUser.LastName IS NOT NULL THEN RegistryUser.LastName ELSE App.LastName END
            ) AS Names
    FROM ConsultingEventConsultant
            LEFT JOIN App
                ON ConsultingEventConsultant.AppID = App.AppID
            LEFT JOIN RegistryUser
                ON App.UserID = RegistryUser.UserID
            WHERE ConsultingEventConsultant.consultingeventid = 56428 
            and ConsultingEventConsultant.CECID != (SELECT TOP 1 CECID FROM ConsultingEventConsultant CEC WHERE CEC.ConsultingEventID = 56428 ORDER BY CECID)
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
             ), 1, 2, ''))
```

To see more about your blank row run the following.  Then you should be able to find the faulty data and fix it or the faulty logic in the query (whichever is causing the blank row).

```
SELECT ', ' +     CONCAT(
                CASE WHEN RegistryUser.FirstName IS NOT NULL AND RegistryUser.LastName IS NOT NULL THEN RegistryUser.FirstName ELSE App.FirstName END,
                ' ',
                CASE WHEN RegistryUser.FirstName IS NOT NULL AND RegistryUser.LastName IS NOT NULL THEN RegistryUser.LastName ELSE App.LastName END
            ) AS Names,
            *
    FROM ConsultingEventConsultant
            LEFT JOIN App
                ON ConsultingEventConsultant.AppID = App.AppID
            LEFT JOIN RegistryUser
                ON App.UserID = RegistryUser.UserID
            WHERE ConsultingEventConsultant.consultingeventid = 56428 
            and ConsultingEventConsultant.CECID != (SELECT TOP 1 CECID FROM ConsultingEventConsultant CEC WHERE CEC.ConsultingEventID = 56428 ORDER BY CECID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend noting when no name is found.  Perhaps this does what you need:

```
select STUFF((SELECT ', ' + 
                     COALESCE(ru.FirstName + ' ' + ru.LastName, 
                              a.FirstName + ' ' + a.LastName,
                              '<NO NAME FOUND>'
                             ) AS Names
              FROM ConsultingEventConsultant c3c LEFT JOIN
                   App a
                   ON cec.AppID = a.AppID LEFT JOIN
                   RegistryUser ru
                   ON a.UserID = ru.UserID
              WHERE cec.consultingeventid = 56428 AND
                    cec.CECID <> (SELECT TOP 1 cec2CECID
                                  FROM ConsultingEventConsultant CEC2 
                                  WHERE CEC2.ConsultingEventID = 56428                                 ORDER BY CECID
                                 )
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
             ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as names
```

Alternatively, you might want to add logic like this:

```
 (ru.FirstName IS NOT NULL OR a.FirstName IS NOT NULL) AND
```

to the `WHERE` clause.